# Amazon Athena ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION query not working

Tags: sql-workbench-j, amazon-athena

I am trying to use SQLWorkBenchJ to add partition to my table in Amazon Athena. The query works fine when run in the Athena Query Editor. It does not work when I run it using SQLWorkbench

```
ALTER TABLE "AwsDataCatalog".mydb.mytable ADD IF NOT EXISTS 
PARTITION (folder = '10036', full = 'fullvalue') LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder/10036/fullvalue/';
```

Note: I have also tried using ALTER EXTERNAL_TABLE

sqlworkbench just returns:

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:

> ALTER TABLE "AwsDataCatalog".mydb.mytable ADD PARTITION (folder = '10036', full >= 'fullvalue') LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder...
>   Failed to run query
>   1 statement failed.

running in query editor

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD PARTITION (folder = '10039', full = 'fullvalue') >LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder/10039/fullvalue/';
```

> Query successful.

any body know how to make this work so I can batch some add partition queries together?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to batch add partitions you can repeat the part including and after `PARTITION` as many times as you need:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD IF NOT EXISTS 
  PARTITION (folder = '10036', full = 'fullvalue') LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder/10036/fullvalue/'
  PARTITION (folder = '10037', full = 'fullvalue') LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder/10037/fullvalue/'
  PARTITION (folder = '10038', full = 'fullvalue') LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder/10038/fullvalue/';
```

Skip the `"AwsDataCatalog"` part of the table name, it should not be needed, and is probably the reason for your problem in SQLWorkbench.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had success qualifying the database and table names with `"AwsDataCatalog"` in ALTER or SHOW PARTITION statements (but it worked in a SELECT).  How about just:

```
ALTER TABLE "AwsDataCatalog".mydb.mytable ADD IF NOT EXISTS 
PARTITION (folder = '10036', full = 'fullvalue')
LOCATION 's3://my-s3-folder/10036/fullvalue/';
```

Would that work for you?